# Can't create a wifi hotspot

Tags: 14.04, broadcom, hot-spot

I'm having problems creating a wireless hotspot using ubuntu. I am able to start a hotspot using windows on the same machine using mHotspot(a third party software).
Network Controller : **BroadCom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)**
I'm using ***Ubuntu 14.04 LTS***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this same issue, do as follows:

1. search for Additional drivers in dash
2. then disable **BroadCom Corporation BCM4313** and restart your computer.
3. then install non-free drivers as `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree`
4. restart your computer
5. search for plasma-nm in software center
6. install it and launch it by typing `kde-nm-connection-editor`
7. [how to setup hotspot is on this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)